# Заполнение формы(?) и отправка

Tags: python

Можно ли отправить данные на сайт для обработки? Ну есть сайт с полем для ввода различной информации, где в конце кнопка «отправить». Я хочу отправлять данные напрямую с помощью `Python`. Сам сайт (необходимо зарегистрироваться): https://remanga.org/panel/add-titles/
И выяснилось следующее:

```js
$('#get_manga_info').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/panel/ajax/parse-titles/',
    data: {
      'link': $('#read_link').val()
    },
    response: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      data = data['content'];
      if (data['add']['authors']) {
        for (var i in data['add']['authors']) {
          $('#id_authors').html($('#id_authors').html() + '<option value="' + i + '">' + data['add']['authors'][i] + '</option>');
        }
      }
      if (data['add']['publishers']) {
        for (var i in data['add']['publishers']) {
          $('#id_publishers').html($('#id_publishers').html() + '<option value="' + i + '">' + data['add']['publishers'][i] + '</option>');
        }
      }
      if ($('#read_link').val().split('/')[2] === 'mintmanga.com') {
        $('#id_age_limit').val('2');
      } else {
        $('#id_age_limit').val('0');
      }
      $('#id_readmanga_link').val($('#read_link').val());
      $('#id_en_name').val(data['en_name']);
      $('#id_rus_name').val(data['rus_name']);
      $('#id_another_name').val(data['another_name']);
      $('#id_description').val(data['description']);
      $('#id_issue_year').val(data['issue_year']);
      $('#id_type').find("option:contains('" + data['type'] + "')").attr('selected', 'selected');
      for (let i in data['genres']) {
        $('#id_genres').find("option:contains('" + data['genres'][i] + "')").attr('selected', 'selected');
      }
      for (let i in data['authors']) {
        $('#id_authors').find("option:contains('" + data['authors'][i] + "')").attr('selected', 'selected');
      }
      for (let i in data['publishers']) {
        $('#id_publishers').find("option:contains('" + data['publishers'][i] + "')").attr('selected', 'selected');
      }
      for (let i in data['categories']) {
        $('#id_categories').find("option:contains('" + data['categories'][i] + "')").attr('selected', 'selected');
      }
      if (data['status'][0] === 'продолжается') {
        $('#id_status').val('1')
      } else if (data['status'][0] === 'завершен') {
        $('#id_status').val('0')
      }
      $('#id_genres').trigger("chosen:updated");
      $('#id_publishers').trigger("chosen:updated");
      $('#id_authors').trigger("chosen:updated");
      $('#id_teams').trigger("chosen:updated");
      $('#id_categories').trigger("chosen:updated");
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert(e.responseJSON['msg']);
    }
  });
});
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  allow_single_deselect: true
});
$('div.chosen-container').css('width', '100%');
$('ul.chosen-choices').addClass('form-control').addClass('form-control-sm').css('padding', '2px 5px').css('border', '1px solid #ced4da').css('background-image', 'none');
$('input.chosen-search-input').css('color', '#6c757d').css('font-size', '.875rem').css('width', '100%');
$('li.search-field').css('width', '100%');
```

Говорят, что надо не через `api`, а через `Cloud`. Наблюдение за кодом... Можно через вебдрайвер попробовать, но на кнопки не нажимает... И если через него, то как изображение загрузить?

Comment: Еще сайт может отправлять запрос и получать ответ, примерно такой:
`{"msg":"","content":{"en_name":"I’m Only a Stepmother, but My Daughter is Just so Cute!","rus_name":"Я мачеха, но моя дочь слишком милая","another_name":"Gyemo-inde ttal-i neomu gwiyeowo","description":"","status":["продолжается"],"genres":["Сёдзё","Романтика"],"type":"Манхва","categories":["Манга"],"issue_year":["2021"],"publishers":["Монархия Рефлай"],"add":{"authors":{},"publishers":{}}},"props":{}}`

Comment: Понял что Ctrl+Shift+T в браузере открывает закрытую вкладку, сохранив ранее введённые данные в <input>-ы. Как это работает? Где хранятся данные, и можно ли их переписать для достижения вышеуказанной цели?